# Are there any use cases for using the HTML5 <link rel> attribute combination of stylesheet and next?

Tags: css, html, stylesheet

The HTML5 spec states:

> Each link created for a link element
>   is handled separately. For instance,
>   if there are two link elements with
>   `rel="stylesheet"`, they each count as a
>   separate external resource, and each
>   is affected by its own attributes
>   independently. Similarly, if a single
>   link element has a `rel` attribute with
>   the value **`next stylesheet`**, it creates
>   both a hyperlink (for the next
>   keyword) and an external resource link
>   (for the stylesheet keyword), and they
>   are affected by other attributes (such
>   as media or title) differently.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-link-rel

What would be a use case for using `rel="next stylesheet"` in the same `<link>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that example was made up simply to illustrate the point that one can use both an external resource and a hyperlink keyword in the same `link` tag. From the [list of link types](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#linkTypes), `stylesheet` seems to be the only external resource type in common use, which is why I guess it was chosen for this example. The `next` could have very well been `prev` or any other hyperlink keyword.

Comment: Even though prefetch alone doesn't work in many browsers, the above you've mentioned does prefetch the stylesheet file. You just have to make sure that `link` tag includes a `title` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the documentation, "The exact behavior for links to external resources depends on the exact relationship,...". What this means is that you have control over how your resources are being retrieved.

Suppose that you have a website that used different stylesheets per page within a series, you can prepare the browser to load in those styles and indicate to search engines of the context that the page has in relation to all of your pages.

```
<link rel="prev" href="about.html">
<link rel="next stylesheet" href="portfolio.html">
```

---

Within this example the benefit again is that the styles for the 'next' "are silently prefetching specified documents and stores them in its cache" https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Link_prefetching_FAQ

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-links

Comment: True, although that’s not an example of using `next` and `stylesheet` together. If you’ve got `stylesheet` as a value of `rel`, the browser will download and cache that for use anyway, without `next`.

Comment: `Stylesheet` is a reserved word so `stylesheet2` would be a custom relationship. Using `next` and `stylesheet` together does cause the file in `HREF` to be preloaded, however, only when a `TITLE` attribute is used.

Comment: @rxgx: oh — I figured if `stylesheet` was used, the file in `href` would be downloaded and applied to the current page, regardless of whether `next` was present or not?

Answer (score 0):

None that I can think of. `next` and `prev` are meant to indicate a sequence of documents meant to be read in order.

Maybe if a sequence of documents ended with an example stylesheet that was also used to style the page before it, that might make sense. Unlikely in practice though.